# NameError in signal handler

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots, nameerror

Here's the program:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()         
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(400, 250, 680, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Programme')

        texte = QtGui.QLabel('On connait :', self)
        texte.move(30, 50)

        i = QtGui.QCheckBox("i", self)
        i.move(30, 70)
        i.setToolTip("C'est l'angle d'incidence de l'onde.")
        i.stateChanged.connect(self.icoche)

        n1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("n1", self)
        n1.move(30, 90)
        n1.setToolTip("C'est l'indice de réfraction du premier milieu. Il correspond au quotient de la vitesse de la lumière dans ce milieu et de la célérité.")
        r = QtGui.QCheckBox("r", self)
        r.move(30, 110)
        r.setToolTip("C'est l'angle de réfraction de l'onde.")
        n2 = QtGui.QCheckBox("n2", self)
        n2.move(30, 130)
        n2.setToolTip("C'est l'indice de réfraction du second milieu. Il correspond au quotient de la vitesse de la lumière dans ce milieu et de la célérité.")

        algo = QtGui.QPushButton("Calculer", self)
        algo.resize(algo.sizeHint())
        algo.move(30, 160)
        algo.setEnabled(False)

        vali = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        vali.move(70, 70)
        vali.setEnabled(False)

        self.show()

    def icoche(self, state):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            vali.setEnabled(True)
        else :
            vali.setEnabled(False)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I check the `i` box, it returns the following error:

> NameError: global name 'vali' is not defined

I tried `self.vali` instead of `vali`, but it doesn't change anything. Where's the error?

Comment: Please read a basic python tutorial on how to use attributes in classes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use self throughout the class to use it as a class attribute. The way you had it it was only in scope for each function individually not both.

```
    self.vali = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
    self.vali.move(70, 70)
    self.vali.setEnabled(False)

    self.show()

def icoche(self, state):

    if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        self.vali.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.vali.setEnabled(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the answer above did not help you. All i can see in this code, is the indentation problem. Your functions are not correctly indented with your class. You are missing one "tab" to all your code after the `class Example(QtGui.QWidget):` With that, every `self` in the functions is recognized by one function only

Comment: That was just a code formatting problem in the question, which has now been fixed.